# How to find pivot tables in LibreOffice Calc file

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am trying to delete a column from a LibreOffice Calc file.  I can't, I get a message "You cannot insert or delete cells when the affected range intersects with pivot table."  Alas, I can't find a pivot table in the file!  Is there a way to get a list of pivot tables in a doc, ideally with the cells they occupy?  My goal here is to seek and destroy.  So if there's a way to get a list of PT's and remove them, that's good too.

Comment: Well, I noticed some cells had a different right-click menu and figured out where the invisible pivot table was living.  I could delete them.  Not a real answer.